# jQuery IE issue, YQL proxy

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, cross-domain, yql

I have a problem here.

I am using YQL & jQuery to get some data;  this is my quick code: [http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/22Ecw/](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/22Ecw/3/)

It doesn't work in IE, I guess any version.

Error :

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
>   jquery-1.4.3.min.js, line 137 character 406

---

And we can see in jsFiddle, FF displays data, IE doesn't.  Anyone have any advice or any idea how can I fix this?

PS. I am using jQuery 1.4.3.

Comment: sorry, updated the question.

console --> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Comment: Some versions of IE do not have console.log so you'd want to remove your debugging statements when testing there.  Please include any error message you're getting from the browser as that will be necessary for debugging.

Comment: I did update the url, should be fine now ! Thanks for this advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to use [`JSONP`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp). The following works in IE9 (and appears to work in IE7 and IE8); note the `callback=?`, which jQuery will handle.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsjobs.brassring.com%2F1033%2FASP%2FTG%2Fcim_home.asp%3Fpartnerid%3D25172%26siteid%3D5235%26LanguageId%3D1%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fform%5B%40name%3D%22frmResults%22%5D%2Ftable'&format=json&callback=?",
        function(data){
            $.each(data.query.results.table[1].tr, function(index, value){
                if (index > 2) {
                    var title  =  value.td[2].p;
                    var id = value.td[1].a.href;
                    var href  = id.split("javascript:window.location='").pop().replace(/'/g, '');
                    var content = '<li><a  href="https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/'+href+'" target="_blank">'+title+'</a></li>';
                    $(".FeaturedJobs").append(content);
                }
            });
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22Ecw/6/

Comment: holly, callback. It is a brilliant answer !!! +10